# Trouble Booting Windows. Black screen, even from boot disk

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, black-screen-of-death

I have an HP Pavilion 690-0067c and there is a problem when trying to boot Windows 10.

When starting up normally, it says “Preparing Automatic Repair” for a moment, and then the screen goes black and nothing happens. It’s been left in that state for 24 hours without progress.

I opened up the diagnostics, and performed the System Extensive Test, and it’s passed every test. Not showing any problems, all tests have been passed.

I have disconnected the power cable and held down the power button to reset it and that did not do anything.

I have also applied defaults to all BIOS settings and that didn’t fix the problem. I then tried to boot from my system recovery flash drive, and bizarrely, the same thing happened. It acted as though it was going to boot for a moment, then went to a black screen again.

The monitor is still on, because it goes blue if it isn’t getting a signal, and I can hear that the computer is functioning, but it won’t display anything.

The display works just fine within the bios settings and the system test screen, but if I try to go past that to windows, whether from the installed version or from the flash drive, it just goes to a fully black screen and stays there.

Comment: If you explore the first screen before it goes black, can you get to the Reset Function?

Comment: I can get to what it says is the “Startup Menu” which includes: System Information, System Diagnostics, Boot Device Options, BIOS Setup, System Recovery.

Comment: If I attempt to use the System Recovery there, it does the same thing, acts like it is going to start, then goes to a black screen. Same as if I boot from the USB drive

Comment: You are going to need to back up the system (drive in a carrier) and then see if you can reinstall Windows. You may wish to see if you can get a USB Recovery Key from HP.

Comment: So the Windows recovery drive isn’t enough?

Comment: It probably will work, but then you need each and every driver from HP. Windows might do some driver updates, but you will certainly need some from HP.

Comment: I can’t seem to see anything from their site about a recovery key. But I don’t know if it will work, because even trying to boot Windows from the USB which should have nothing to do with the current setup on the computer does the same thing

Comment: See if you can get the HP Hardware Test application on bootable USB Key. The current testing suggests you have a bad hard drive.